# Reflection Property.SetValue(

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, system.reflection

I have the following class to create objects from a delimited line:

```
public class Mapper<T>
{
    public T Map(string line, char delimiter)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(line));

        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(delimiter))
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(delimiter));

        var splitString =  line.Split(delimiter);

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        if(properties.Count() != splitString.Count())
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Row has {splitString.Count()} columns but object has {properties.Count()}.");

        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        for (var i = 0; i < splitString.Count(); i++)
        {
            var prop = properties[i];
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var valType = Convert.ChangeType(splitString[i], propType);
            prop.SetValue(obj, valType);
        }

        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

If I call the map method with a delimited string it will populate all of the properties on the object with the delimited values from the line.

However when I call this from the following:

```
public class CsvStreamReader<T>
{
    private readonly Mapper<T> _mapper;
    public CsvStreamReader(Mapper<T> mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    } 



    public IEnumerable<T> ReadCsvFile(string filePath, bool hasHeader)
    {
        if(hasHeader)
            return File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                       .Skip(1)
                       .Select(x => _mapper.Map(x, ','));

        return File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                   .Select(x => _mapper.Map(x, ','));
    } 
}
```

It will return a list of T but all of the properties will be null and won't have been set.

**Update**: Just realised my class wasn't a class but was actually a struct.

Comment: use debugger to see why its returning null. I don't think linq query can cause such problem. because its not related to that. what is `_mapper`?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. For all we know you pass the wrong `T` to your mapper, or your file is empty or contains no data. You also can't rely on `GetProperties()` to return properties in any particular order. The Linq part is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Sorry _mapper contains the Map<T> function.

Comment: You're assuming that the order of the splitted string is the same as the order of the properties returned with reflection? Looks vulnerable.

Comment: Just realised my class wasn't a class but was actually a struct, oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your `Mapper<T>` work when `T` is a value type, you need to set its properties **while boxed as an object**.  Create your `obj` as an `object` using the the non-generic [`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx), set its properties using reflection, then finally cast the it to the required type when returning it:

```
public class Mapper<T>
{
    readonly List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
    
    public T Map(string line, char delimiter)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("line");

        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(delimiter))
            throw new ArgumentException("delimiter");

        var splitString = line.Split(delimiter);

        if (properties.Count() != splitString.Count())
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Row has {0} columns but object has {1}", splitString.Count(), properties.Count()));

        // Create as a reference (boxed if a value type).
        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        // Set the property values on the object reference.
        for (var i = 0; i < splitString.Count(); i++)
        {
            var prop = properties[i];
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var valType = Convert.ChangeType(splitString[i], propType);
            prop.SetValue(obj, valType);
        }

        // Cast to the return type unboxing if required.
        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PEj4yI).

Note that your code should not depend on the order of properties returned by `Type.GetProperties()`.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
> order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
> depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
> order varies.

Thus I modified your code to order by name.  You might choose to select another strategy such as using [data member order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813(v=vs.110).aspx) for [data contract types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx).

Finally, you might want to reconsider your design of using mutable structs, see [*Why are mutable structs “evil”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) for some reasons why.  To restrict your `Mapper<T>` to work only for reference types, you can add the following `where` constraint:

```
public class Mapper<T> where T : class
{
}
```